# pick latest record in join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

Below is my query to update manager field in one table. The problem I am facing is I want to pick the user (NRH.AffectedUserNumber) with lastest start date in RH Table.

```
WITH [NewReqHeader]
AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
           OVER(ORDER BY RH.StartDate DESC) AS rowid
          , RH.RequestId
          , RH.RequestType
          , RH.RequestStatusID
          , RH.AffectedUserNumber
          , RPD.TaskId
          , RPD.HotelID
          , RH.StartDate
      FROM DBO.RequestPermissionDetail RPD
           JOIN DBO.RequestHeader RH ON  RH.RequestId = RPD.RequestId
                    AND RH.RequestType = 2
                    AND RH.RequestStatusID = 20
                    AND RPD.TaskId = 923
)
UPDATE #Facility_Manager
SET    Manager = NRH.AffectedUserNumber
FROM   #Facility_Manager FM
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [NewReqHeader] NRH ON  FM.FacilityId = NRH.HotelID
                AND ISNULL(FM.FacilityId ,'') != ''
WHERE  FM.SecPermissionCount > 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a `PARTITION BY` clause to the `ROW_NUMBER` function to get a count by each HotelID.
Then just limit the WHERE clause to

```
WHERE  FM.SecPermissionCount > 1 AND NRH.rowid = 1
```

Comment: could you please explain how?

Answer (score 0):

```
update fm
set 
  Manager = (
    select top 1 AffectedUserNumber
    from 
    NewReqHeader nrh
    where fm.FacilityID = nrh.HotelID
    order by StartDate desc
  )
from 
#Facility_Manager fm
where
SecPermissionsCount > 1
```